# MainActivity don't start

Tags: android

Hi i am a beginner in android studio.I want start my first mobile app.
I have just one problem; i have this code:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText editText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.d("MainActivity", "onCreate");

        editText = findViewById(R.id.test);
        editText.setText("Pippo");
    }
}
```

and xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/oooo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textVieww"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:editable="false"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

But activity don't start.
Error is:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
        at com.example.prova.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
```

I have a fatal error and MainActivity don't start.  How can i do?

Comment: EditText editText  change edittex to TextView in your java file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your activity, you have the following:

```
 EditText editText;

 editText = findViewById(R.id.test);
```

but in your xml you have:

```
  <TextView  <-- this is a TextView, not an EditText
        android:id="@+id/textVieww"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:editable="false"
        android:text="TextView" />
```

An EditText isn't a TextView, so that's why your code is crashing

---

change either your xml to have an EditText or your java to TextView, depending on what you actually want

---

Furthermore, i don't know what `findViewById(R.id.test);` is referencing, because nothing in this layout has an ID of `test`, it should be

```
findViewById(R.id.textVieww);
```